# How to check each sub-directory and list files in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a dynamic menu system that I plan on using in creating a template for sites that I create.

I tried to find any similar to this, but I specifically don't want to use a database.

Basically my idea is that the content directory will recurse into creating a menu so that each php page is a menu item and each directory is the top-level menu.

For this, I am trying to list all php files of a directory and set `foreach` to create an `<li>`. I have been successful in listing the files of a single directory but I am not able to list recursive directories.

This is what I have so far

```
<ul>
<?php
chdir('content');

    foreach(glob('*') as $directory){ 
$dirname=ucwords (str_replace('_', ' ', $directory));
    if (is_dir($directory)){ 

print "<li>".$dirname."<ul>";
$mitem = glob("$directory/*.{php}", GLOB_BRACE);
// now we print our links as a unordered list

foreach ($mitem as $menu){
$menu= basename($menu, '.php');
$smenu=ucwords (str_replace('_', ' ', $menu));
print "<li><a href='$menu'>$smenu</a></li>";
}
print '</ul></li>';
}

 else
{
// now we print our links as a unordered list
$dirname= basename($directory, '.php');
$dirname=ucwords (str_replace('_', ' ', $dirname));

print "<li><a href='$directory'>".$dirname."</a><li>";

}
}


?>
</ul>
```

This will loop through one set of directories and show the correct structure I want except for two things. 1) I don't get nested directories. 2) For some reason there is a new `<li></li>` after each entry that is not a directory for the top directory only. Can someone help me fix the code so 1 and 2 are resolved. You can see the image below for the result.

[image: result]

Comment: Use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

Comment: i did look at this, but i don't know how to go about editing my code to incorporate it as each example uses a code that includes elements my code doesn't have at the moment like keys

Comment: Have you looked at this example? http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/PHP-SPL-RecursiveDirectoryIterator-Tutorial.html#7